# How can I export a different value for COMPOSE_PROFILES in different included makefiles?

Tags: docker-compose, makefile

I'd like to have a number of different makefiles, one for each [docker compose profile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/). Each of these makefiles should be included from the root makefile.

```
Makefile # includes the other makefiles

docker_compose_profile_makefiles/
  profile_a.Makefile
  profile_b.Makefile
  ...
```

I'd like each makefile to have many targets that will eventually call docker compose with the appropriate exported value of `COMPOSE_PROFILES` for that file, **without having to re-specify the same value in each target**.

How can I get all targets in `profile_a.Makefile` to use exported variable `COMPOSE_PROFILES=profile_a`, and all targets in `profile_b.Makefile` to use exported variable `COMPOSE_PROFILE=profile_b`?

I've tried using both the `export` top level directive and `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`, and it seems like the last write wins ... across all of the makefiles.

### Example Code

#### `Makefile`

```
.PHONY: all
include docker_compose_profile_makefiles/*.Makefile

export COMPOSE_PROFILES := default

all:
    echo env_var: $$COMPOSE_PROFILES
```

#### `docker_compose_profile_makefiles/profile_a.Makefile`

```
# profile_a.Makefile
export COMPOSE_PROFILES := profile_a

profile_a:
    @echo "profile_a: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to $(COMPOSE_PROFILES)"
```

#### `docker_compose_profile_makefiles/profile_b.Makefile`

```
# profile_b.Makefile
export COMPOSE_PROFILES := profile_b

profile_b:
    @echo "profile_b: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to $(COMPOSE_PROFILES)"
```

### Actual Behavior

```
$> make make all
echo env_var: $COMPOSE_PROFILES
env_var: default
$> make profile_a
profile_a: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to default
$> make profile_b
profile_b: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to default
```

### Desired Behavior

```
$> make make all
echo env_var: $COMPOSE_PROFILES
env_var: default
$> make profile_a
profile_a: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to profile_a
$> make profile_b
profile_b: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to profile_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Make's `include` is just textual substitution.  There's no "scoping" etc. involved.  The result after an `include` is identical to replacing the `include` statements with the complete text of each included makefile then running make on the result, no more and no less.  Variables in make are global by default so if you set one then reset it later, it will have the second value when recipes are expanded.

Also, you are confused about "export".  It doesn't mean "export to an included makefile".  It means, "when you run a shell to invoke a recipe, put this value into the shell's environment".  It is totally unrelated to what you want to do (and, adding `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is a terrible idea, in any makefile, IMO and you should not do it).  Your use of `export` doesn't matter because your profile recipes are not using the shell's environment to retrieve these values (and even if they were it would be the same).

You can either make your variables unique by name based on the target (for example) and choose the right one, or you can use target-specific variables.  Those are the only types of "scoping" available in makefiles.

As an example of using target-specific variables, you could write your makefiles like this:

```
.PHONY: all
include docker_compose_profile_makefiles/*.Makefile

COMPOSE_PROFILES := default

all:
        echo value $(COMPOSE_PROFILES)
```

and:

```
# profile_a.Makefile
profile_a: COMPOSE_PROFILES := profile_a
profile_a:
        @echo "profile_a: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to $(COMPOSE_PROFILES)"
```

and:

```
# profile_b.Makefile
profile_b: COMPOSE_PROFILES := profile_b
profile_b:
        @echo "profile_b: COMPOSE_PROFILES is set to $(COMPOSE_PROFILES)"
```

Both are described in more detail in this set of blog posts (start with the oldest one and work your way forward as you understand them): https://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/

Comment: _"you are confused about 'export'. It means, 'when you run a shell to invoke a recipe, put this value into the shell's environment' It is totally unrelated to what you want to do'_ ... This is exactly what I meant by _"I'd like each makefile to have many targets that will eventually call docker compose with the appropriate exported value of `COMPOSE_PROFILES` for that file, **without having to re-specify the same value in each target"**_

It looks like there isn't any DRY way to ensure all targets in each file have the same value of the variable, other than re-specifying it on each target?

Comment: Correct.  Make does not make any distinction based on "file" when including files.  It's like C or C++: when you include a file there's no differentiation made by the compiler between content in one file and another.  Of course, in C or C++ you have other scoping facilities, which makefiles don't have.  All contents of all makefiles (from the command line, included, whatever) are completely parsed into an internal graph of nodes (targets) and edges (prerequisite relationships).  Any idea of what file the node was defined in isn't relevant to make.

Comment: Just to note, target-specific variables can be _inherited_ through the graph, from their parent nodes.  But this only works if make follows the graph through that node.  So if you invoked make to start at the edge node, it wouldn't pick up any variables set in any parent nodes.